# AnimatedOpacity and AnimatedBuilder with opacity not performing same animation

Tags: flutter

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  bool _foo = true;
  static const _curve = Curves.linear;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    )..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  void _animate() async {
    if (_foo) await _controller.forward();
     else await _controller.reverse();
    _foo = !_foo;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _controller.value,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: _curve,
              child: box,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: _curve),
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Opacity(
                  opacity: _controller.value,
                  child: box,
                );
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _animate,
              child: Text('Animate'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get box => Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

From the screenshot, you can see I am using same `Curve` for both `AnimatedOpacity` and `AnimatedBuilder`, but output is still not the same, can anyone tell me why?

I'm new to Flutter, so no idea if I am making some silly mistake. 
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: AnimatedOpacity has a duration of 500ms while the _controller has a duration of 1000ms

Comment: @EdwynZN On putting both duration same, you'd see AnimatedOpacity takes 2 times more than an AnimatedBuilder to show/hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnimatedOpacity` is an `ImplicitAnimationWidget`, which means it construct a `Tween` based on the `opacity` value you give it (and the curve and duration). An implicit animation changes according to the current value and the new one, but because you give to it the `_controller.value` it changes its velocity based on the velocity change of the the controller (change of rate of a change of rate, sounds like inception). Think like maths, the `AnimationBuilder` gives you a velocity based on a curve(like first differential) and `AnimatedOpacity` does the same so you don't need to build a controller, but because you gave it the `_controller.value` (which changes with a given velocity) it gives you the change of rate of that velocity (sounds like second differential)

Check this example where I gave `AnimatedOpacity` a simple `double` (1 or 0 depending at the same time I start the `AnimationController`). They have the same curve and duration so the animation seems basically the same

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  bool _foo = true;
  double value;
  static const _curve = Curves.linear;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    );//..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    value = _controller.value;
  }

  void _animate() async {
    setState(() {
      value = _foo ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    });
    if (_foo) await _controller.forward();
     else await _controller.reverse();
    _foo = !_foo;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: value,//_controller.value,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
              curve: _curve,
              child: box,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: _curve),
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Opacity(
                  opacity: _controller.value,
                  child: box,
                );
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _animate,
              child: Text('Animate'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get box => Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use same duration

```
duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
```

use flipped curve in reverseCurve

```
_animation = CurvedAnimation(
  curve: _curve,
  reverseCurve: FilppedCurve(_curve),
);
```

or

```
AnimatedOpacity(
  opacity: value,//_controller.value,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  curve: _foo?_curve:FlippedCurve(_curve),
  child: box,
),
```